# Continuity and differentiability of a composite function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $
     f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} x^2, & y >0 \\
         0, & y=0\\
   -x^2, & y<0  \end{array}  \right .
  $

I've got to check out whether $f(x,y)$ is continous and differentiable at $(0,0)$.
By limit definition, I've got:

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}x^2=0$ if $y>0$,

and $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}-x^2=0$ if $y>0$

or $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}|x^2|=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}|-x^2|=0$.

So, as the  differential $df(0,0)=0$, we check out:
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}|\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq \displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}x=0$, so this function is differentiable.

Are these arguments correct and enough to show everything?

Comment: Differentiability is not correct. It is correct that this is not bigger than $1$ but that doesn't prove anything. You should see if this limit equals zero or not. It does not equal zero. Take the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: @Poppy It's not correct that the derivative is not bigger than $1$, since a derivative isn't even a number. It's a linear map $\mathrm{d} f(0, 0) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Thesinus: You forgot a square root in the denominator in the calculation of the derivative. Plug it in, adjust the result accordingly and it's going to be correct.

Comment: @Adayah You are right. I used a bad term. I thought to say the limit. Also, Thesinus made a mistake as you noticed. So, it is differentiable.

Comment: thx, I've corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

For checking the continuity condition you can use polar coordinates (it works well for some problems) so that the limit 
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$
Since in the limit you have a $r$ with degree $2$ the limit exists and is equal to $0$. For checking that the derivatives exists you must check it for both directions. It means that checking
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0+\Delta x,0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}$$
which is zero since $y=0$ in $f(\Delta x,0)$. In $y$ direction you obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta y\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0,0+\Delta y)-f(0,0)}{\Delta y}$$
which again is zero based on the definition of $f(x,y)$.

So both first derivatives exists and the function is continuous so you can deduce that it is differentiable.

Actually $f(x,y)$ is a surface which you can visualize it as a cylinder (the definition of cylinder is given in the Stewart Calculus book) which the $z$-axis is the continuity between the two parts of the surface and since it is not dependent on $y$ it does not change along the $y$-axis and the derivative with respect to $y$ is zero everywhere.